# Elements changing location depending on window size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a register form on the right side of the window, I want it to stick on the bottom but not to reach the top, which looks that I successfully did, there is one problem, depending on the screen resolution, the form changes its location, for example on my second monitor which is 1920x, I don't see the button, I see it from E-Mail, how can I make it hold the same position on all resolutions?

I tried googling but I did not find something to work, sorry if I am being too noob but this has been giving me issues for a while.. I want to find for once the good way to make it and use that in future too...

This is how it should look

[image: How it should Look]

This is how it goes wrong on other monitors:
[image: How it should not look]

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/registerpage.css">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers' rel='stylesheet'>

<title>Register Page | Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="content">

<div id="main">
    <form id="loginform" action="/action_page.php">
        <label class="usernam" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Insert your username...">

        <label class="usernam" for="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Insert your password...">

        <label class="usernam" for="pass2">Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="pass" name="pass2" placeholder="Insert your password again">

        <label class="usernam" for="useremail">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="pass" name="userem" placeholder="Insert your email">

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</div>

<!-- <img id="userimg" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-2/24/man-icon.png"/> -->
<!-- <img id="passimg" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/webiconset/application/24/Register-icon.png"/> -->

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
html,body {
    overflow: auto;
}

.background-image
{
    background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/beautiful-light-city-wallpaper-hd-1080p.jpg");
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(3px);

}

.content {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#main {
    line-height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align:center;
    border: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    left: 600px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;

    margin-top: 132px;
    margin-left: 399px;
    margin-right: 399px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 10px 35px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 10px 35px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 12px 10px 35px -11px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#loginform {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 5px;
    top: 10%;
    height: auto;
}

#loginform #username, .pass {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.usernam {
    font-family: 'Bangers';
    font-size: 30px;
}

/*#userimg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 425px;
    bottom: -278px;
}

#passimg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 425px;
    bottom: -400px;
}*/


input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

/*#copyright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -555px;
    left: 580px;
}*/
```

This is giving me headaches, this is how it looks on my monitor:
[image: sadda]

And this is how it looks from a 1920x1080
[image]

I tried using px and also % the result is the same with both :@ please... I don't understand..

Alright, I fixed that but now, the icons that I add doesn't hold their position, how it should look on all screens.
[image: asfsaf]

How it looks on a bigger resolution..
[image: asfaf]

Div Code:

```
<div id="main">
    <form id="loginform" action="/action_page.php">
        <label class="usernam" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Insert your username...">
        <img id="userimg" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-2/24/man-icon.png"/>

        <label class="usernam" for="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Insert your password...">
        <img id="passimg" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/webiconset/application/24/Register-icon.png"/>

        <label class="usernam" for="pass2">Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="pass" name="pass2" placeholder="Insert your password again">
        <img id="pass2img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/webiconset/application/24/Register-icon.png"/>

        <label class="usernam" for="useremail">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="email" class="pass" name="userem" placeholder="Insert your email">
        <img id="emimg" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dario-arnaez/genesis-3G/24/Emails-Folder-icon.png"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#userimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9%;
    right: 84%;
}

#passimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26%;
    right: 84%;
}

#pass2img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    right: 84%;
}

#emimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    right: 84%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only positioning you need is:

```
#main {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

(Here you can edit the values of right as you wish.)

Please remove properties like:

```
#main {
    left: 600px;
    margin-top: 132px;
    margin-left: 399px;
    margin-right: 399px;
}
```

which are "magic" numbers.
Fix the height of your form holder and it will be done.

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell me why right and not left and why are those called "magic numbers"? :D

Comment: Magic numbers because they are randomly set and are not round numbers. These values are good on some screens, but on other resolutions they do not fit.
Here we use right positioning, because the element is closer to the right border. You can use left too, but then the values should be bigger and is harder to be calculated.

Comment: Now I have issues with some icons, edited my first post above :s
@NadezhdaSerafimova

Comment: Please set the icons as background images of the input elements. Example: #username {
  background: url('../path-to-your-img') #fff no-repeat left center;
 }